# Find words starting and ending with dollar signs $ in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am looking to find and replace words in a long string. I want to find words that start looks like this: $test$ and replace it with nothing.

I have tried a lot of things and can't figure out the regular expression. This is the last one I tried:

```
preg_replace("/\b\\$(.*)\\$\b/im", '', $text);
```

No matter what I do, I can't get it to replace words that begin and end with a dollar sign.

Comment: isn't `$` reserve for the pattern end in REGEX?

Comment: Yes, that's why you have to escape it

Comment: the double escape got me confuse XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes and remove the double escape.

```
$text = preg_replace('/\$(.*?)\$/', '', $text);
```

Also a word boundary `\b` does not consume any characters, it asserts that on one side there is a word character, and on the other side there is not. You need to **remove** the word boundary for this to work and you have nothing containing word characters in your regular expression, so the `i` modifier is useless here and you have no anchors so remove the `m` (multi-line) modifier as well.

As well `*` is a **greedy** operator. Therefore, `.*` will match as much as it can and still allow the remainder of the regular expression to match. To be clear on this, it will replace the entire string:

```
$text = '$fooo$ bar $baz$ quz $foobar$';
var_dump(preg_replace('/\$(.*)\$/', '', $text));
# => string(0) ""
```

I recommend using a [**non-greedy**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html) operator `*?` here.  Once you specify the question mark, you're stating (**don't be greedy**.. as soon as you find a ending `$`... stop, you're done.)

```
$text = '$fooo$ bar $baz$ quz $foobar$';
var_dump(preg_replace('/\$(.*?)\$/', '', $text));
# => string(10) " bar  quz "
```

### Edit

To fix your problem, you can use `\S` which matches any non-white space character.

```
$text = '$20.00 is the $total$';
var_dump(preg_replace('/\$\S+\$/', '', $text));
# string(14) "$20.00 is the "
```

Comment: Does this work for specific words though? What if my string was "$20.00 is the $total$".  I would only want it to find the $total$ and ignore the $20.00.

Comment: Will the strings between `$` and `$` every have space characters between?

Comment: Awesome thanks. My major problem was using double quotes instead of single. After fixing that I could tell something was happening.

Answer (score 3):

There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries `\b`:

1. Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
2. After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
3. Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

`$` is not a word character, so don't use `\b` or it won't work. Also, there is no need for the double escaping and no need for the `im` modifiers:

```
preg_replace('/\$(.*)\$/', '', $text);
```

I would use:

```
preg_replace('/\$[^$]+\$/', '', $text);
```

Comment: I would even add \n to it so it would be something like [^$^\n]

Comment: @PHPlover: Good point, but I would use `\s` instead of `\n`, to exclude *all* whitespace characters: `[^$\s]`.  (The OP has said in a comment that no whitespace is allowed.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) to help you out on 'quoting':

```
$t = preg_replace('/' . preg_quote('$', '/') . '.*?' . preg_quote('$', '/') . '/', '', $text);

echo $t;
```

From the docs:

> This is useful if you have a run-time string that you need to match in some text and the string may contain special regex characters.
>
> The special regular expression characters are: . \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -

Comment: Using `preg_quote()` over a single non-dynamic character is overkill. Just escape it. On a side note, if you were to use `preg_quote()`, do not forget the second (delimiter) parameter. So if you used `/` as delimiter, then use `$regex = '/someawesome' . preg_quote($dynamic, '/') . 'regex/';`

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to your use of word boundary markers (`\b`), you actually want the inverse effect (`\B`)-- you want to make sure that there ISN'T a word character next to the non-word character `$`.

You also don't need to use capturing parentheses because you are not using a backreference in your replacement string.

`\S+` means one or more non-whitespace characters -- with greedy/possessive matching.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/S8BTJ))

```
$text = '$foo$ boo hi$$ mon$k$ey $how thi$ $baz$ bar $foobar$';
var_export(
    preg_replace(
        '/\B\$\S+\$\B/',
        '',
        $text
    )
);
```

Output:

```
' boo hi$$ mon$k$ey $how thi$  bar '
```